# Is it possible to override a rails engine model association in a decorator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

I'm using a rails engine which defines a class with the following relation:

```
module Blogit
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    ...

    belongs_to :blogger, :polymorphic => true
    ...

end
```

I'm trying to override this association in a decorator file. Namely, I do not want this association to exist if possible.

In my decorator file, i'm using a class_eval to extend the class definition.

```
Blogit::Post.class_eval do
  ...
end
```

but I can't seem to override or destroy this relation. Anyone know how to do this?